# How many concurrent login allowed for Salesforce Community users?

Tags: community, limits

We got error while doing performance test against the Community Portal for login multiple users concurrently.

```
<h1>Unable to Process Request</h1>
<h2>Concurrent requests limit exceeded.</h2>
<br><br>To protect all customers from excessive usage and Denial of Service attacks, we limit the number of long-running requests that are processed at the same time by an organization. Your request has been denied because this limit has been exceeded by your organization. 
Please try your request again later.
<br><br>
```

Question is how many users can login in one go[like concurrently]? to Community Portal.

Thanks for you time :)

Answer (score 0):

We have done performance testing for our community on a full staging sandbox. 
The process we follow is below

1. Submit total number of concurrent transactions to salesforce during the performance testing window through a salesforce ticket
2. Salesforce reviews and provides approval post which we can execute in the window we got approval for
3. Salesforce usually enables additional monitoring during this window to ensure we dont monopolize the resources during testing

We typically get approval for testing 50-70 concurrent community users. At one point we did till 300 concurrent but currently they dont give approvals for such high number of concurrency.

It also depends on usage of your community you anticipate in production based on which you calculate concurrency.

The goal should be optimize your apex/lightning performance issues and not to stress test salesforce instance.